# Passing from one to three text field in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

In order to make my log in screen easy to use, I would like to :

- when user is on the username textfiled ⟹ go to password textField when the return key is pressed
- when user is on the password textfield ⟹ go to the email textField when the return key is pressed
- when user is on the email (last) textField ⟹ make the log in button tapped when the return key is pressed

The first part work, wich means I can move from username to password textField, but when I press <kbd>↩</kbd> in the password keyboard, nothing happens.

Any idea ?

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var emailSignUpTextField: UITextField! = UITextField ()
@IBOutlet var userNameSignUpTextField: UITextField! = UITextField ()
@IBOutlet var passwordSignUpTextField: UITextField! = UITextField ()


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {


    if (userNameSignUpTextField){
        userNameSignUpTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordSignUpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    else {
        passwordSignUpTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        emailSignUpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    return true

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userNameSignUpTextField.delegate = self
    passwordSignUpTextField.delegate = self
    emailSignUpTextField.delegate = self


}
```

Comment: Firs of all make sure `textFieldShouldReturn` is called at all.

Comment: Thank you, how could i do that ?

Comment: Your if () is just checking to see if userNameSignUpTextField is nil or not. Assuming you've connected it up in interface builder, it will never be nil. Perhaps `if userNameSignUpTextField == textField`, or check to see which is currently the first responder, or use a tag... Also, you shouldn't need to resign first responder—setting another field to be the first responder will automatically resign any existing first responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check all outlet connection are correct or not.

Now change if condition to `isFirstResponder()`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    if (userNameSignUpTextField.isFirstResponder()){
        userNameSignUpTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordSignUpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    else if(passwordSignUpTextField.isFirstResponder()) {
        passwordSignUpTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        emailSignUpTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```

Hope it will help you